# Django's URL Dispatcher not extracting kwargs

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have configured url patterns a ton of times in Django before.
Suddenly it's not working and I have no idea why...

I'm using Django REST Framework, and I'm testing the API using Django's RequestFactory.
This is my URL pattern:

```
url(r'^samples/(?P<sha256>\w+)/?$', endpoints.SampleAPI.as_view())
```

This is how I tested the GET request:

```
from django.test import RequestFactory
factory = RequestFactory()
request = factory.get('/samples/somehash')
response = endpoints.SampleAPI.as_view()(request)
```

This is what I'm trying to do:

```
class SampleAPI(APIView):
    def get(self, request: Request, *args, **kwargs) -> Response:
        sha256 = self.kwargs.get('sha256', None)
```

The URL gets resolved and I go into the method, but for some reason, `sha256` is always `None` (The `kwargs` dictionary is always empty!).
Weird thing is that I did the **exact same** thing in 2 of the other services I'm developing (only another name for the keyword argument), and they **work**.

Do you guys see anything I'm missing here?

**EDIT:** Updated the post to show **how** I tested the urls

Comment: Strike the `self` before kwargs and try again.

Comment: I tested this locally with `Django 1.9.2`, `djangorestframework 3.6.3` and `Python 3.5.3` and it worked for both `kwargs` and `self.kwargs`. Are you sure that this url is resolved to `SampleAPI`? Did you try to put some `print()` or `pdb` in `get()`?

Comment: @Melvyn it's the same result

Comment: @Kamil It does resolve to SampleAPI, I've debugged it to be sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, It's a stupid mistake that I didn't think about.

I shouldn't have used `RequestFactory` in my tests, because the arguments do not get passed to the view this way.
The correct way is using Django's test `Client`:

```
from django.test import Client
client = Client()
response = client.get('/samples/somehash')
```

Sorry for the newbie mistake here.

Comment: No problem. It also shows why none of us got the problem. You mentioned Request Factory, but I doubt many linked it to the django.test package and just assumed (like me) it's some package that generates Http requests in a sensible manner :)